# Using a Standard User Account to learn Programming on OS X - 'sudo' required?

Tags: ruby, macos, terminal, admin, homebrew

I want to learn programming, and am worried I will mess things up with my computer. There are also many packages, etc. that I will only want to try out and after some time things can get quite messy. That's why I have created a separate user account only for programming, etc. so that in case it gets too messy, I can just delete the whole account and start anew.

I now wanted to try out some ruby, and was required to install homebrew. That required me to log in as sudo however. I thus did this from my admin account. Then I had to install ruby by running

> brew install ruby

This, again, needs to be done from the admin account / with sudo rights. But my whole point was to have this separate user account to not have everything on the system and clutter things up. I want to have it locally in my user account. Why does this not work, what am I doing wrong?

Also, if I try to type in my sudo password in the terminal of my coding account, it doesn't accept it. I can install things when I am logged into my admin account, but am not able to install anything from my coding account, by just typing the sudo pw in the terminal. why is that?

Comment: Who told you you're "required" to install homebrew?  OS X has ruby 2.0 right out of the box.

Comment: Please only ask about a single topic in a question.  Break your "Also,..." paragraph into a separate question, since it's a distinct topic from your earlier paragraphs.

Comment: Also, you don't need to use `sudo` to install Homebrew (and furthermore the docs actively discourage you from doing so). Refer to the second sentence in the [installations docs](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/a381b597d3ebf40887b50657df269d867a209eb7/docs/Installation.md).

Comment: There are lots of online ruby tutorials that run in-browser (e.g. codeschool, code academy, etc.).  Nothing to install...well...assuming you have a browser.